# google map search box result by clicking on enter key or by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am working on example where i have prepared a google place search box which give me direct output to map by auto complete tool.but i want following to type of more facility for search

1. if i write something in search box and press enter key from keyboard,search box should work
   2.i want button beside search box which give me result after clicking on it if i have entered value in search box.
   EXAMPLE : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hq0b49/)

```js
   $(function () {
         var lat = 44.88623409320778,
             lng = -87.86480712897173,
             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

         //zoomControl: true,
         //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

         var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             zoom: 13,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             panControl: true,
             panControlOptions: {
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
             },
             zoomControl: true,
             zoomControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
             }
         },
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 draggable: true,
                 position: latlng,
                 map: map,
             });

         var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
         var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
             types: ["geocode"]
         });

         autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
             infowindow.close();
             var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }

             moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
             $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
         });
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
             $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
            document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
             infowindow.close();
                     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                     geocoder.geocode({
                         "latLng":event.latLng
                     }, function (results, status) {
                         console.log(results, status);
                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                             console.log(results);
                             var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                 lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                 placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                             moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                             $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                         }
                     });
         });
        
         function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
             marker.setPosition(latlng);
             infowindow.setContent(placeName);
             //infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>

Address:
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" style="text-align: left;width:357px;direction: ltr;">
<br>
            latitude:<input name="latitude" class="MapLat" value="" type="text" placeholder="Latitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>
            longitude:<input name="longitude" class="MapLon" value="" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 350px;width: 500px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.if i write something in search box and press enter key from keyboard,search box should work**

You can use google.maps.[Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) which you places markers on a map or position the map. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pbbhH/60/).

```
function selectFirstResult() {
    infowindow.close();
    var firstResult = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({"address":firstResult }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
            $("input").val(firstResult);
        }
    });   
 }
```

**2.i want button beside search box which give me result after clicking on it if i have entered value in search box.**

You need to add an [Event listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) for that event. The code will be executed when those events are received by calling `addListener()` to register event handlers on the object. Example:

```
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
  searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('searchbox'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', processPlacesSearch);
}

var button = document.getElementById('searchbutton');
var searchbox = document.getElementById('searchbox');

button.onclick = function () {
  var location = searchbox.value;
  processButtonSearch(location);
}
```

Hope this helps!